# We are doing a project together

Tags: word-usage

So we have got a project to work on, and I wanted to tell my mate that I can't finish it by my own alone so how can I say that grammatically.

Hey mate do not expect me to do the project alone, I will need help.

Hey mate please don't keep any expectations from me that I can do it by my own I will need help.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey mate I need your help to finish this project.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say something like this:

> Hey, mate, I can't do the project alone. I'll need your help.

It's better to tell him whose help you will need, if you want him to help you.

If you want to use the longer version, you'll need to correct it. *keep expectations from me* means to avoid telling you about expectations. That isn't what you're trying to say.

> Hey, mate, please don't have [or *get*] the expectation of me that I can do the project on my own. I will need your help.

Note that we say *on my own*, not *by my own*. Also, this is pretty wordy. If you want to convey the same thing in a bit simpler way, you could say this:

> Hey, mate, please don't expect me to be able to do the project on my own. I'll need your help.

Another variation, a bit less formal:

> Hey, mate, please don't get the idea that I can do the project on my own. I'll need your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept it as the answer, if you believe that it is the answer that you need.